# Finding intersections in rows of sparse matrices

Tags: r, performance, matrix, set, sparse-matrix

As an MCVE, consider a sparse matrix like this (see also the `dput` output at the end)

```
> X
10 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] .    . .    .    5.45 .    .    1.75
 [2,] .    . 5.05 1.75 5.45 3.60 .    .
 [3,] 5.45 . 2.45 .    .    .    .    .
 [4,] .    . 5.05 .    6.50 .    .    .
 [5,] 5.45 . .    .    .    2.85 .    .
 [6,] .    . .    .    5.95 .    .    1.75
 [7,] 5.45 . .    1.60 .    .    2.45 .
 [8,] 5.45 . .    1.60 .    .    2.45 .
 [9,] 5.45 . 2.45 .    .    .    .    .
[10,] .    . 5.05 1.75 5.45 3.60 .    .
```

For example, if the intersection given is `c(1L, 3L)`, then I want to know the indices of rows having non-zero elements on their first and third column, i.e. `c(3, 9)`. For the intersection `c(3L, 4L, 5L)`, it should be `c(2, 10)`.

Note that in my application

1. The matrix `X` may have hundreds of thousands of rows and/or thousands of columns.
2. Each intersection typically has 2 to 3 elements, up to 6 elements at most.
3. There will be hundreds of different intersections to be `lapply`ed, so you'll probably want to do some pre-processing.

Here is what I'm doing now

```
> intersections <- list(c(1L, 3L), c(3L, 4L, 5L))
> nonzero.rows <- by(X@i, rep(1:ncol(X), times=diff(X@p)), list)
> find.row.id <- function(intersection, nonzero.rows) Reduce(intersect, nonzero.rows[as.character(intersection)]) + 1
> lapply(intersections, find.row.id, nonzero.rows=nonzero.rows)
[[1]]
[1] 3 9

[[2]]
[1]  2 10
```

Profiling suggests this is one of the biggest bottlenecks in my library. Can you make it faster?

---

```
> dput(X)
new("dgCMatrix", i = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 9L,
1L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 0L, 5L
), p = c(0L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 19L, 22L, 24L, 26L), Dim = c(10L,
8L), Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL), x = c(5.45, 5.45, 5.45, 5.45,
5.45, 5.05, 2.45, 5.05, 2.45, 5.05, 1.75, 1.6, 1.6, 1.75, 5.45,
5.45, 6.5, 5.95, 5.45, 3.6, 2.85, 3.6, 2.45, 2.45, 1.75, 1.75
), factors = list())
```

Comment: `ind = c(1, 3); which(rowSums(X[,ind] != 0) == length(ind))`

Comment: Have you tried to code this using Rcpp(Armadillo)?

Comment: @F.Privé Not yet. I know C but aren't really familiar with C++, and I wonder if it's worth the effort. How much performance improvement can I expect with RcppArmadillo?

Comment: Not sure it is worth it.. Look at my answer that is both simple and  should be fast.

Comment: Do you have many overlapping intersections? e.g. `c(2, 3)` and `c(2, 3, 5)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reprex

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(1)
X <- rsparsematrix(10000, 1000, 0.3)
intersections <- replicate(10000, sample(ncol(X), sample(2:4)))
```

#### Testing some solutions

Your solution:

```
system.time({
  nonzero.rows <- by(X@i, rep(1:ncol(X), times=diff(X@p)), list)
  find.row.id <- function(intersection, nonzero.rows) Reduce(intersect, nonzero.rows[as.character(intersection)]) + 1
  lapply(intersections, find.row.id, nonzero.rows=nonzero.rows)
}) # 3.4 sec
```

Recoding `X` as a list of vectors (not far from your solution, but more elegant):

```
system.time({
  X2 <- as(X, "dgTMatrix")
  X3 <- split(X2@i + 1L, factor(X2@j + 1L, levels = seq_len(ncol(X))))
  lapply(intersections, function(ind) Reduce(intersect, X3[ind]))
}) # 3.4 sec
```

Reducing by starting with smaller sets:

```
system.time({
  X2 <- as(X, "dgTMatrix")
  X3 <- split(X2@i + 1L, factor(X2@j + 1L, levels = seq_len(ncol(X))))
  lapply(intersections, function(ind) {
    X3.ind <- X3[ind]
    len <- lengths(X3.ind)
    Reduce(intersect, X3.ind[order(len)])
  })
}) # 3.7 sec
```

Solution proposed in the comments:

```
system.time({
  lapply(intersections, function(ind) {
    which(Matrix::rowSums(X[, ind] != 0) == length(ind))
  })
}) # 46 sec
```

Solution proposed at https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2018/09/17/intersection-of-multiple-vectors/:

```
system.time({
  X2 <- as(X, "dgTMatrix")
  X3 <- split(X2@i + 1L, factor(X2@j + 1L, levels = seq_len(ncol(X))))
  lapply(intersections, function(ind) {
    tally <- integer(nrow(X))
    for (elements in X3[ind]) {
      tally[elements] <- tally[elements] + 1L
    }
    which(tally == length(ind))
  })
}) # 1.7 sec
```

You can easily parallelize the `lapply()`.

Comment: This turns out to be slower than the `by` approach. However, when I replace `factor(X2@j + 1L, levels = seq_len(ncol(X)))` with `X2@j + 1L`, it runs as fast as `by`.

Comment: Wow, you have to test it on a larger example (many `ind`). The preprocessing step should not be the bottleneck in your real application..

Comment: See my edit where I test different solutions (a new one). This is not fantastic improvement though.

Comment: The for loop in the last solution seems like a disaster, but it's the fastest? That's interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: It is a for loop over 2 to 4 elements, so it is fine.